# api.nuget.org/v3/index.json not available

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, restore

Please tell me in which direction to dig?

I'm trying to install nuget packages via nuget restore, but the address https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json (from NuGet.config) gives
Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Which is logical, because This address is not accessible from the browser. Issued by Can’t reach this page.

There is access to arbitrary sites (Yandex, etc.).

The only thing I could come up with was to add https://api.nuget.org to Internet Options -> Trusted sites and lower the Security Level for this zone to a minimum. Did not help.

Comment: This address normally is accessible, so it's probably something with firewall or network settings